# Единственное ли число прилагательного при двух дамах-существительных?

Tags: единственное-множественное-число

> А в XIII веке ворота поменяют своё название на «дель Пополо» – в честь
>   одноимённой церкви и площади.

Comment: По крайней мере, ошибки нет. Если нет разночтений, предпочтителен вариант с единственным числом.

Comment: Спасибо, Люсенька!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А в XIII веке ворота поменяют своё название на «дель Пополо» – в честь **одноимённой церкви и площади.**

Розенталь  [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#з_05](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#%D0%B7_05)

Определение, относящееся к двум или нескольким существительным – однородным членам, ставится **в форме единственного числа,** если по смыслу сочетания ясно, что определение относится не только к ближайшему существительному, но и к последующим, например: уличный шум и грохот; летний жар и зной; морской прилив и отлив;

Comment: Жасминка, примеры у Розенталя "неудачные" - в одни ворота... Ср. ***Окосевший бойфренд и гёрлфренд*** - не-а. Ну да, тут разный род; но щас что-нито придумаю.

Comment: Вот, из Р. же, и род единый: ***построить каменные дом и гараж; полированные шкаф и комод***...

Comment: Так здесь в случае  ед. ч.  (каменный дом и гараж) дом каменный, а гараж неизвестно какой, а у нас-то ясно, что "одноименный" относится к обоим существительным.